# Django's adding ?next/ to url

Tags: django, url

I'm using django decorator:

```
@permission_required(login_url='/login/', perm='auth.can_view')
```

But it's adding '?next=/' to my url (=> /login/?next=/). How to fix it?

---

**UPD**: Thanks to @benjaoming, i resolve this problem:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.has_perm('auth.can_view'), login_url='/login/', redirect_field_name='')
```

Comment: ... You *don't* want it going back to the view that required permissions?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yes, i don't want it going back to the view, that required permission.

Comment: It's logging you in so that you can *get* the permissions.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, yes i understand this (shure, if i correctly translated your comment :) ) But i just need to cut off that '?next=/'

Comment: So then where *would* you like it to go after logging in?

Comment: Custom html page: maybe with a picture or something like that. It's not important. I just want to cut down that "tail".

Comment: Use the decorator user_passes_test. Put a value in settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL and add redirect_field_name="bollocks" to the keyword arguments of user_passes_test.

Comment: @user_passes_test(lambda u: u.has_perm('auth.can_view'), login_url='/login/', redirect_field_name='ufo')

Comment: For more inspiration, simply refer to the very readable source code that django has: django/contrib/auth/decorators.py

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @benjaoming, i resolve this problem:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.has_perm('auth.can_view'), login_url='/login/', redirect_field_name='')
```